# load and display PNG image (Not base64) requiring basic authentication in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, binary

I'm so stuck on this. I need to retrieve a picture e.g. http://ip:port/icon_contact.png using JavaScript from another server requiring basic authentication. The server can't give base64. Don't worry about x-domain restriction.
thanks in advance,
louenas

Comment: Give us some details... Why do you need to use javascript to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "retrieve"? And do you want the user prompted for the authentication, or do you want to provide it?

Comment: I'm writing a native mobile app using JavaScript. All the app's code reside on the client side. I could get the PNG binary files using Ajax but I couldn't figure out how to display them on an HTML page.

Comment: Then the second part of my answer should help a bit -- you want to convert the binary data into a `data://` URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly — which is by no means certain — you want to retrieve the binary data of an image file providing basic authentication information directly (not via the user).

You should be able to do this with the `XMLHttpRequest` object (you can supply auth information in the `open` call), but to read binary data from the response I'm fairly sure you'll have to stray into brand-new and/or implementation-specific stuff. Here are links to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx), [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest), and (fairly new) [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) docs. Microsoft's `XMLHttpRequest` has [`responseBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534368%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), Mozilla's (Firefox's) has `mozResponseArrayBuffer`, and I believe the W3C docs discuss binary data [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#response-entity-body0).

To *display* the image having loaded it via the above, you could transform the binary data into a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Url) *(more correctly "data URI", but no one says that)* string and assign the result to an `img` tag's `src`. You'd have to convert from whatever the browser-specific binary stuff was into the [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (for the data URL). *(You probably don't have to write the conversion yourself, a quick search indicates that people have been tackling this problem and you can reuse [and possibly contribute back to] their efforts...)*

The bad news is that IE only supports data URIs as of IE8, and it limits them to 32k, so you'd have to nifty slicing techniques like [Google does for search preview](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html).

Once you have the `data://` string, the `img` tag part is easy. If you're not using a library:

```
var img, element;

img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = /* ... the data URI ... */
element = /* ... find the element you want to put the image in, via
                 document.getElementById or document.getElementsByTagName
                 or other DOM traversal ... */;
element.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: This couldn't work because getting the image requires the credentials.

Comment: But the code you gave doesn't use XmlHTTPRequest. If I use XHR I can provide the credentials but in return I get binary data of the icon. And when I used the same approach as yours, I couldn't find a way how to set the credentials :(

Comment: @loueas: Please re-read the answer, from the beginning. First, you get the data with `XMLHttpRequest` (which I suspect will be tricky). Then you transform it into a `data://` URL. Then you use that data URL with the `img` tag. I didn't write all the code for you, I pointed to the information I think you need to write it. The code sample is just the third part of the puzzle, the one that's easily dashed off. Good luck with it.

Comment: I tried that. I don't know if it is possible to transform the icon's binary data (retrieved using XHR) to a data URI.

Comment: Also keep in mind that IE only supports data URIs as of version 8, and even then it limits their size to 32KB.

Comment: @loueas: Yes, it is. Regardless of which flavor of `XMLHttpRequest`, they all make the actual data available to the script. At which point you can access the byte values and create the base-64 string.